# Problems with Azure Website and OAuth

Tags: azure, oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, azure-web-app-service

I have my MVC .NET project Published in an Azure Website.

The problem is that I get an `Exception` that says **"Access denied"** when I create my `UserCredential`:

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
            , scopes
            , userName
            , CancellationToken.None
            , new DataStore()).Result;
```

My GoogleAPIs Console Credential looks like this (`Client Secret`):

[ClientSecret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av4Ju.png)

Then, in my Azure Portal I configured the `Authentication/Authorization`:

[Azure Portal Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOC19.png)

I'm sure the problem is *credential problem* cause when I try it in localhost it works OK. The problem arrives when it's deployed in azure, using exactly the same credentials.

- Have I missed any step?
- Is there a problem in my Google credential?
- Should I enable anything else in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, I would suggest you try to use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow instead. For detailed steps about how to use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow, please refer to [this article](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc). I tested the code and show the User Id to the page index. It works fine in Azure Web App.

Here is the HomeController:

```html
    public class HomeController : AsyncController
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
                AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (result.Credential != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = result.Credential.UserId;
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the result:

[image]